# Astronomers: What magazines do you subscribe to?

Tags: discussion

The Astro mods are considering the possibility of getting some ads put in astronomy-related magazines for Astronomy.SE. We could easily look up some popular magazines, and we probably will. But I thought I'd take a moment to ask our community, because you may make us aware of some that are important to you.

So what (astronomy-related) magazines do you subscribe to?

(Physics or science in general might be good target magazines too.)

Comment: How did it go? I think it was a great idea! If I were an astronomer I would try to figure out how to about give a short talk "How to ask and answer in Astronomy SE" at some conference.

Comment: @uhoh If I recall correctly, nothing ever came of it. I can't remember if Rhys or Don was spearheading it.

Comment: [this situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359012/303080) sounds like some direct advertisement to people skilled in the art/active in the field *might be* a big help. Politics SE really got their community under control quite nicely, this one is harder because it's a very popular topic among both the general public and (likely very busy) active researchers who can't be bothered, and because it's so new there aren't a lot of older established people who have both the extra time to spend and the detailed knowledge to address the issues. Perhaps what's needed is a knowledgeable community?

Answer (score 4):

One magazine that I am aware of is "All about space" which has a fairly broad reach of about 63,000 readers, probably more since that measurement was taken.

It focuses a lot around space and planetary sciences and covers some far reaching topics such as the formation of the universe and creation of galaxies, as well as new discoveries and launches.

I know it is certainly a good choice based in the UK, not sure how this compares in other countries though.